# Highcharts: How to adjust size of bar chart with respect to spacing/size of bars?

Tags: highcharts

I have a bar graph (note: the length of a bar spans horizontally. conversely, a column graph spans vertically. See below.) My series data can either become a long list or a short list so the number of bars varies between many and few. If I have many bars, my graph needs more height to maintain the same space between bars and maintain the width of the bars. How can I set the height of the graph to ensure that these are fixed?

I looked into a scrollbar for the vertical axis, but I didn't like this because the browser may have it's own vertical scrollbar. I also found advice on dynamically resizing the graph to fit the window, but this is won't work if I have more bars than would fit within a maximized window. So I think the best idea would be to have a graph that sizes with the number of bars. If the bar graph is greater than the page height, the browser's vertical scrollbar will come into action.

Bar graph:

```
===
==========
=============== ]---- width of bars needs to be maintained. 
[spacing between bars also needs to be maintained.]
=======
===========
=== <--- a new bar would simply go here, and chart would increase height by 1 bar width.
```

Comment: One other option is to let the data contain as many points as you want but have a default zoom level that only shows the first N points. Then the user can zoom out/in while maintaining one chart size. This will mean that the bar width and spacing would change when the user zooms. Do you know a max number of points ahead of time?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'd rather the bar widths maintain. Zooming in and out seems a little awkward for a bar graph.

Comment: Then you should go the route of determining a size for a chart based on how many data points you want to show with your desired spacing. It will only be ballpark, of course. We do something similar but not for your reasons. We want the labels on the xAxis (bar chart like you) to not overlap each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I have found for this is to determine the size by a simple count of the categories I will need on the server side.

When loading the page, I start with the height needed for the chart's top and bottom margin.
I do a count of my data, and multiply by however much space I need (usually 20, 25 pixels per category, in my cases).

Then set the height of the container accordingly.

I usually do this with php on page load.  I'm sure a javascript implementation wouldn't be difficult to achieve.